# Мужик и баба

Tags: лексика

Вот, подумалось: так вышло, что слово "мужик" в современном языке не носит в себе оскорбительного оттенка, наоборот даже, придает оттенок мужественности тому, о ком говорят: "вот это мужик!", "мужик сказал, мужик сделал" и т.д. Одновременно слова "баба" и "девка" сейчас имеют явно грубый и даже оскорбительный оттенок.

Answer (score 1):

Если обратиться к словарю, то окажется, что вы не совсем правы. У слова МУЖИК несколько значений: 1. Крестьянин, а также вообще человек из простонародья (прост.). *Мужика не день, а год кормит* (посл.).; 2. То же, что мужчина (разг.). *Дельный мужик*; 3. То же, что муж (прост.). *Соседка жалеет своего мужика*; 4. Невоспитанный и невежественный человек (разг. пренебр.). *Мужик сиволапый*.

Слово БАБА тоже многозначное: 1. Крестьянка, а также вообще женщина из простонародья (преимущ. о замужней или вдове) (прост.). *Деревенские девки и бабы*; 2. То же, что женщина (иногда пренебр. или шутл.) (прост.). *Бабы на лавочке судачат*; 3. То же, что жена (прост. и обл.); 4. В сочетании с именем собственным -- уважительно о простой пожилой женщине (часто в обращении), а также (прост. и обл.) то же, что бабушка. *Уборщица баба Дуся. Жили-были дед и баба* (сказочный зачин); 5. В детской речи: бабушка (часто в обращении). *Внуки просятся к бабе с дедой*.

Как видите, и МУЖИК, и БАБА почти во всех своих значениях являются просторечными или разговорными. Актуализация одного из значений обусловлена ситуацией общения и вовсе не означает, что других значений нет. Если же речь идет о каком-то гендерном превосходстве МУЖИКА над БАБОЙ, то можно лишь повторить общеизвестную истину: язык отражает то, что есть в жизни. У нас общество традиционное: хоть равноправие и декларируется, но патриархат  и Домострой глубоко в нас сидят. В украинском языке МУЖ вообще - *чоловік*, а жена, видимо, - полчеловека. :-))

Answer (score 0):

Ну современными словарями тут не отделаешься. нужен исторический аспект.
Начну с девки. Негатиная коннотация возникла недавно и совершенно окказионально. Никаких предпосылок к тому не было. Девка в основном значении и тогда и сейчас - либая незамужняя женщина. Дворяне, правда, больше пользовали слово "девица", но такой уж явной негативной окраски как мужик или баба по отношению к "благородному" лицу оно не несло.
Баба всегда было оскрбительным, но только по отношению к мужчине или "благородной" женщине. Ну а мужиками величали в основном крепостных, негативного оттенка оно не несло. Отсюда, видимо, и развились современные представления о уничижительности "бабы" и уважительности "мужика".